# A vector field whose Jacobian(?) is the identity is an Euler field?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a connection $\nabla$ in the tangent bundle of a manifold $M$, and a vector field $v$ on $M$ satisfying 
$\nabla_w(v)=w$,
for all vector fields $w$ on $M$.  Let $P\in M$ be a point where $v$ vanishes.

My hope is that  I can find an isomorphism of $M$ with a vector space, identifying $v$ with the Euler field (at least locally near $P$).